# Switch statement fires all @html.partials and not the selected value

Tags: javascript, umbraco, partial-views

I'm setting up a function to send specific e-mail based on a selection from a select dropdown menu. Based on the selection the specific mail needs to be send. The mails are being send from a partialview that works as a handler.

When the page loads every partial view is rendered and all the mails are being send, and I can't see why this shouldn't work.

This is made in umbraco, and the partials are made from the backoffice so there is no controller to render from. and I've tried switch and if statements but can't really get it to work the way I want to.

```
//My attempt at the function for the rendering of partials    
function SendMail(){
    var select = document.getElementById("foo");
    var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    if (selected == 1) {
        $.ajax({ url: @Html.Partial("Web/Partial1", @Model.boo) })
    }

    if(selected == 2){
        $.ajax({ url: @Html.Partial("Web/Partial2", @Model.boo)})
    }

    //switch (selected) {
    //    case '0':
    //        alert(selected);
    //        break;
    //    case '1':
    //        alert(selected);
            //   $.ajax({ url: Html.Partial("Web/Partial1", Model.boo)})
    //        break;
    //    case '2':
    //        alert(selected);
         //   $.ajax({ url: Html.Partial("Web/Partial2", Model.boo)})
    //
```

//This is my select html.

```
<select id="foo" onchange="SendMail()">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Vælg en type</option>
<option value="1">Ordrebekræftigelse</option>
<option value="2">Betalingsmail</option>
</select>
```

Comment: which one doesn't work - the if or the commented out switch? I would expect the switch to work as you are checking against strings whereas the if statements are checking against ints (which you have not parsed the value of the option to be)

Comment: neither of them works, both attempts fires all of my partials.

Comment: I don't see how a switch could fire both unless the switch was being called multiple times - try putting a console.log at the top of the function and see how many times it is called

Comment: If I comment out the ajax calls in the switch statement, then it works like its supposed to, and the console.log shows up once for each time i change to selector. But if the codes are not commented out then it ignores the switch and just renders both of the ajax calls.

Comment: could be because you are using the full partial as the url instead of an actual url - I would expect to see something like `url: '@Url.Action("Partial2", "Web", Model.boo)'` not sure if I got the action name and controller the correct way round in that (action name comes first)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use `Ajax.BeginForm`. In the form set the `Html.DropdownListFor()` or `DropDownList()` with its parameters and call `onchange($(this).closest('form').submit())`

example select.cshtml:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        "_PartialMailChanger",
        "Manage",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            // GET or POST (I assume GET in your case)
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            UpdateTargetId = "changeMailContainer",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        },
        new { id = "formChangeMailPartial" }))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("MailChangeDropdown", YOUR_LIST_OF_SELECTITEMS, new
        {
            onchange = @"$(this).closest('form').submit()"
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the syntax error actually near Html. Partial, it's not accepting Html.Partial("Web/Partial1", Model.boo) as a URL.(see by yourself by removing and it will not give error SendMail Not defined)

So I suggest, create a method in the controller

```
public ActionResult CallPartial(int selected){
  /// you can use switch case also 
   if(selected== 1)
     return PartialView("yourpartial1",YourModel);
    if(selected == 2)
     return PartialView("yourpartial2",YourModel);
 }
```

and in ajax response, append partial view to required div

```
 function SendMail(){
 var select = document.getElementById("foo");
var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

$.get( "YourControllerName/CallPartial",{selected : selected }, function( 
 data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  });
}

 <div class='result'></div>
```

Comment: That still loads both partials unfortunately, and i get an: Unchaught Reference error: sendmail() is not defined on this onchange="SendMail()".